# Reiniciar juego de la serpiente JavaSwing

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy intentando darle funcionalidad a un botón (`JButton btnReset`) de reinicio para que el juego se reinicie cuando el usuario lo pulse una vez se ha terminado una partida, el código no sigue el modelo MVC, únicamente tiene un Main
(`MainW`) que lanza la app y llama al controlador (`SnakeGame`) que tiene toda la lógica del progama. Pero al terminar una partida cuando se pulsa el botón, no hace nada, da la sensación de que el botón no esté puesto a la escucha, algo que ya comprobé. Pego ambas clases, cualquier ayuda será bienvenida...

```
package Controlador;

import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import Vista.MainW;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class SnakeGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3575398609620689669L;
    // Constantes del juego
    private final int B_WIDTH = 300;
    private final int B_HEIGHT = 300;
    private final int DOT_SIZE = 10;
    private final int ALL_DOTS = 900;

    private final int RAND_POS = 29;
    private final int DELAY = 140;

    // coordenadas de la serpiente por sus ejes X e Y
    private final int x[] = new int[ALL_DOTS];
    private final int y[] = new int[ALL_DOTS];

    private int dots;
    private int apple_x;
    private int apple_y;

    private JButton btnReset;

    public JButton getBtnReset() {
        return btnReset;
    }

    private boolean leftDirection = false;
    private boolean rightDirection = true;
    private boolean upDirection = false;
    private boolean downDirection = false;
    private boolean inGame = true;

    private Timer timer;
    private Image ball;
    private Image apple;
    private Image head;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public SnakeGame() {
        initSnakeGame();
    }

    private void initSnakeGame() {
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setFocusable(true);
        btnReset = new JButton("Reiniciar");
        btnReset.setBounds(104, 204, 86, 23);
        add(btnReset);
        btnReset.setVisible(false);
        btnReset.addActionListener(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));
        loadImages();
        initGame();

    }

    private void loadImages() {
        ImageIcon iid = new ImageIcon("Images/ball.png");
        ball = iid.getImage();

        ImageIcon iia = new ImageIcon("Images/apple.png");
        apple = iia.getImage();

        ImageIcon iih = new ImageIcon("Images/snake.png");
        head = iih.getImage();
    }

    private void initGame() {

        dots = 3;

        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
            x[z] = 50 - z * 10;
            y[z] = 50;
        }

        locateApple();

        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        setLayout(null);


        timer.start();

    }

    private void checkApple() {
        if (x[0] == apple_x && y[0] == apple_y) {
            dots++;
            locateApple();
        }
    }

    private void checkCollision() {

        for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {

            if ((z > 4) && (x[0] == x[z]) && (y[0] == y[z])) {
                inGame = false;
            }
        }

        if (y[0] >= B_HEIGHT) {
            inGame = false;
        }

        if (y[0] < 0) {
            inGame = false;
        }

        if (x[0] >= B_WIDTH) {
            inGame = false;
        }

        if (x[0] < 0) {
            inGame = false;
        }

        if (!inGame) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        doDrawing(g);
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        if (inGame) {

            g.drawImage(apple, apple_x, apple_y, this);

            for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
                if (z == 0) {
                    g.drawImage(head, x[z], y[z], this);
                } else {
                    g.drawImage(ball, x[z], y[z], this);
                }
            }

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

        } else {

            gameOver(g);
            btnReset.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    private void gameOver(Graphics g) {

        String msg = "Game Over";
        Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
        FontMetrics metr = getFontMetrics(small);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.setFont(small);
        g.drawString(msg, (B_WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, B_HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    private void move() {

        for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
            x[z] = x[(z - 1)];
            y[z] = y[(z - 1)];
        }

        if (leftDirection) {
            x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        }

        if (rightDirection) {
            x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }

        if (upDirection) {
            y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        }

        if (downDirection) {
            y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }
    }

    private void locateApple() {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        apple_x = (r * DOT_SIZE);
        r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
        apple_y = (r * DOT_SIZE);
    }

    // clase privada para manejar las flechas del teclado
    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!rightDirection)) {
                leftDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!leftDirection)) {
                rightDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!downDirection)) {
                upDirection = true;
                rightDirection = false;
                leftDirection = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!upDirection)) {
                downDirection = true;
                rightDirection = false;
                leftDirection = false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == getBtnReset()) {
            initGame();
        }
        if (inGame) {

            checkApple();
            checkCollision();
            move();

        }

        repaint();
    }
}
```

Y aquí pego el Main que lanza la app:

```
package Vista;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import Controlador.SnakeGame;

public class MainW extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2873342823046220930L;
    public MainW() {
        initUI();
    }
    private void initUI() {
        
        add(new SnakeGame());
        setResizable(false);
        pack();
        setTitle("Snake game");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                try {
                    JFrame frame = new MainW();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pero al terminar una partida cuando se pulsa el botón, no hace nada,
> da la sensación de que el botón no esté puesto a la escucha, algo que
> ya comprobé.

El botón si captura el evento y por tanto se puede hacer la nueva partida.

El problema que se presenta es que ignoras restablecer la variable `inGame` a su valor inicial `true` para que `doDrawing()` continúe dibujando las imágenes; y el otro detalle es esconder el botón.

Entonces sencillamente...

```
if (e.getSource() == getBtnReset()) {
    initGame();
    inGame=true;//variable restaurada al valor de inicio del juego
    btnReset.setVisible(false);//boton invisible al usuario
}
```

Conforme este programa vaya creciendo se hará evidente la necesidad de usar un método que haga reinicios de: tiempos de juego, puntajes, variables como `inGame`, etc... Es una sugerencia nada mas.

PD. También como sugerencia, usa la llamada a `repaint()` en un método como `move()` por ejemplo y no en el método `actionPerformed()` ;D